# How to combine a voxelmap of cubes?

Tags: mesh

I'm expanding on [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140673/how-to-combine-multiple-cubes-with-double-faces/140677#140677) question I asked previously.

I'm working on a programming idea and I'm prototyping it in Blender. I need to create a map from a series of blocks. As seen below.
[image: Cube model map]

I then want to select and remove all faces on the interior where a face is duplicated. In my previous answer, one user suggested a two step process to select the interior faces:

- Remove Doubles
- Select > Select all by trait > Interior Faces

But that doesn't scale up. If I make a larger object, interior faces includes a lot of incorrect selections.

Is there a way to remove the double-sided faces on the inside of this mesh *without using scripting*?

Comment: Starting from the other end .. would the Remesh modifier, (blocks mode) be able to do anything for you?

Comment: No. I want the cube faces on the inside to be removed so I can do some program-like manipulation. Re-mesh changes the mesh.

Answer (score -1):

try these videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6L3gxMC5AqY

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcM7wBlvA4c

They won't solve your problem but they will highlight the fact that there's no answer to your problem because it hasn't been created. I believe it will require some scripting and creativity to get what you are after.

I was looking for an answer to this for hours. The best I could come up with is to do join functions and then clean up the results. Boolean functions will not work because the faces being exactly in the same location will cause rounding errors.

Edit: oh, someone made a script: [How to combine multiple cubes with double faces?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140673/how-to-combine-multiple-cubes-with-double-faces?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Edit: Oh, Blender 2.81 will have a voxel re-mesher? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEnRAgvIsf8