# How can I close holes in hexahedral meshes?

Tags: modeling, mesh, scripting, bmesh

I want to be able to close holes in hexahedral meshes, I need that in order to produce physical computations on the model.
How can I achieve that in the most efficient way? Simple "F" doesn't work.
Thank you for your attention.
[image]

Inside of the mesh:
[image]

The mesh can be more irregular:

[image]

All vertices (and therefore edges) are shared as if doubles were removed by using <kbd>M</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> (*Merge By Distance*). The mesh, while irregular, consists of pockets formed by 6 quads.

A hole can be defined by a place where a face could be created without adding any edges (marked red below); ideally, a hole would be also a place where 2 faces could be created by adding a single edge first (marked green below):

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VG-LFbub8k&t=254s&ab_channel=tinkertillie

File:
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126861/discussion-on-question-by-mikhail-gavrilec-how-can-i-close-holes-in-hexahedral-m).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Axis-aligned edges

Assuming each edge is parallel to either of x, y, z axes, it's trivial to look for U-patterns by taking an edge1 and calculating vector from one of its vertices to another, then taking a linked edge2 with a different vector, and then an edge3 linked to edge2 with a vector which is a reverse of edge1's vector. Then just pass the vertices of that pattern to a face constructor to ensure there's a face.

```
import bpy, bmesh


def main():
    me = bpy.context.active_object.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
    example = bm.faces[0]  # copy settings from this face
    for edge in bm.edges:
        for verts in missing_faces(edge):
            try:
                bm.faces.new(verts, example)
            except ValueError:
                # you can drop try... if you decide to use `is_face_missing`
                pass
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)


def missing_faces(start_edge):
    for v2 in start_edge.verts:
        v1 = start_edge.other_vert(v2)
        vec1 = v2.co - v1.co
        for neighbor_edge in (e for e in v2.link_edges if e is not start_edge):
            v3 = neighbor_edge.other_vert(v2)
            vec2 = v3.co - v2.co
            if vec1 == vec2:  # the edge continues away from v1
                continue
            for far_edge in (e for e in v3.link_edges if e is not neighbor_edge):
                v4 = far_edge.other_vert(v3)
                vec3 = v3.co - v4.co
                if vec3 == vec1: # and is_face_missing(start_edge, far_edge): 
                    # far_edge is parallel to start_edge
                    yield v1, v2, v3, v4
                    break
    
            
#def is_face_missing(edge1, edge2):
#    for face in edge1.link_faces:
#        if edge2 in face.edges:
#            return False
#    return True


main()
```

[image]

### Generalized version

for each face A, take two opposite edges A1 and A2. Using loops instead of the edges directly (and `link_loop_radial_next`), get connected faces to them. Iterate over A1 loop to find such face B, and over A2 loop to find such face C, that an edge B2 (opposite to A1=B1) and an edge C1 (opposite to A2=C2) have a connecting edge. If so, ensure there's a face by trying to create a new one.

[image]

```
import bpy, bmesh


def main():
    me = bpy.context.active_object.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
    for face in bm.faces:
        for verts in traverse_face(face):
            try:
                bm.faces.new(verts)
            except ValueError:
                pass  # face already exists here
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)


def traverse_face(face):
    loop = face.loops[0]
    for _ in range(2):
        opposite_loop = loop.link_loop_next.link_loop_next
        yield from traverse_loop_pair(loop, opposite_loop)
        loop = loop.link_loop_next


def traverse_loop_pair(loop1, loop2):
    cache = list(opposite_edges(loop2))  # cache repeatable inner loop
    for edge1 in opposite_edges(loop1):
        for edge2 in cache:
            result = connection(edge1, edge2)
            if result:
                yield result
    
    
def opposite_edges(loop):
    for _ in loop.edge.link_faces[1:]:
        loop = loop.link_loop_radial_next
        yield loop.link_loop_next.link_loop_next.edge


def connection(edge1, edge2):
    e1_v1, e1_v2 = edge1.verts
    for e2_v in edge2.verts:
        for edge in e2_v.link_edges:
            v = edge.other_vert(e2_v)
            if v is e1_v1:
                return e1_v2, v, e2_v, edge2.other_vert(e2_v)
            if v is e1_v2:
                return e1_v1, v, e2_v, edge2.other_vert(e2_v)
    return None


main()
```

Comment: Thank you for your hard work. but ther is something I can't understand. why it works not in all cases? Before script https://ibb.co/yQ7s85r after the script https://ibb.co/M1Qdwpk

Comment: @MikhailGavrilec this script assumes all edges are parallel to one of the axes. I think it can be improved, but first I would have to understand the generalized problem, e.g. do I see correctly that there can be a 5-edge-pole? https://i.imgur.com/FYHLahy.png

Comment: Yeah, that is correct. there can be 5 edge-pole and also cells can be distorted(not parallel to one of the axes)

Comment: I have an idea how to do that, by using `link_loop_radial_next` and `link_loop_radial_prev`, I'll tinker with it tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you a lot.

Comment: @MikhailGavrilec see 2nd part.

Comment: This algorithm works fairly well. Thank you for your work.