# Extracting surface from mesh with interior geometry

Tags: modeling, mesh, selection-tools

I'm importing a voxelized mesh in Blender from another software and it comes with separate geometry for every cube in it, insides included. I would like to only select the surface of it (faces touching air so to speak) to be able to detach it. Something akin to a hull creation would also help.

This is how the model looks
[image]

Decimation does not work on it because of the interior edges.

What I'm looking for is a way to select only the "surface"
[image]

Co-planar selection select some hidden geometry too, as it cuts full layers.
The other closer selection is Sharp Edges, but that one leaves the wholes in the extracted corners.

I've also tried selecting Interior Meshes but it seems to not work properly as it always selects some faces from outside too.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Added sample blend file:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Could you add the model blend file to your question so we can try things on it? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: I would just manually go and select the sides with border select, but you might have better results using the remesh modifier, or just doing “convex hull” since you mentioned that.

Comment: In solid view you can select the whole surface with the border selection tool from a few view angle.

Comment: @batFINGER studying your answer right now, it looks like you have to start with separate cube objects? Managed to get it to work for that case, but not for my case (which gives me hope I didn't waste my time writing my solution, though it was still a nice exercise). I'll definitely keep your code, as merging cubes is something I need often. Wondering if I should maybe move my answer there and mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah sep objects, it joins with the bmesh.  Then removes from joined mesh. Sure I wrote a similar answer with kdtree can't find. Always a good exercise to see another way of doing this. I don't use lambda enough.. Ultimately Bettsies answer on a joined mesh is prob way to go, or the way the OP will go. No issue from me if you add answer there.

Comment: @MartyFouts I've added the sample, for the other suggestions selecting interior seems to go haywire.

Comment: What is not clear until you added the blend file is that your cubes are triangulated.  If you select one diagonal and similar by length and dissolve those edges (or tris to quads) there will be more chances of scripts designed for 6 quad faced cubes to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove the diagonals.**

With some minor pre-processing to make remove the diagonals and feed into answer of duplicate question [How to combine multiple cubes with double faces?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140673/how-to-combine-multiple-cubes-with-double-faces)

- The non diagonal edges of your meshes are marked as sharp, will use that to get diagonals which are not.
- Dissolve the diagonals
- Then this becomes a cube problem, below using script from my answer in dupe, or alternatively feed inot Markus Von Broady's answer to get same result.

TEst script. Run in OBJECT mode.  Converts to quads and removes  interior geometry of all selected objects.

```
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector
from mathutils.bvhtree import BVHTree
import bpy
from bpy import context

scene = context.scene
for ob in context.selected_objects:
    mw = ob.matrix_world
    me = ob.data

    # remove diagonals

    sharps = [False] * len(me.edges)
    me.edges.foreach_get("use_edge_sharp", sharps)
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(me)

    bmesh.ops.dissolve_edges(
            bm,
            edges=[e for e, s  in zip(bm.edges, sharps) if not s],
            )

    # as in dupe answer.

    bvhtree = BVHTree().FromBMesh(bm, epsilon=1e-7)
    faces = bm.faces[:]

    remove = list()
    while faces:        
        f = faces.pop()        
        pair = bvhtree.find_nearest_range(f.calc_center_median(), 1e-4)
        if len(pair) > 2:
            # mark face for removal
            remove.extend(p[2] for p in pair)

    bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
    bmesh.ops.delete(bm,
            geom=[bm.faces[i] for i in set(remove)],
            context='FACES_KEEP_BOUNDARY',
            )

    bmesh.ops.remove_doubles(bm,
            verts=bm.verts,
            dist=1e-7)

    bm.to_mesh(me)
    me.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

I moved this answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/238127/60486)

I thought of adding support for triangles, but OP's own answer removes the triangles anyway, and merging doubles is tricky if there are overlapping squares that are triangulated inconsistently (well, maybe not very tricky but still more steps watering down the gist of the solution).

Everything worked fine for me, after <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd> *"Limited Dissolve"*, but batFINGER's way seems safer: select a diagonal, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, *Sharpness* (*Length* with minimal *threshold* should work if future visitor doesn't have the comfort of selecting smooth edges), right-click, <kbd>D</kbd> *Dissolve Edges*.

Now run the script.

Comment: Was considering that if there are 2 * n faces (tris) then sorting edges by length and wiping the first n could be an option not requiring marked sharp.

Comment: @batFINGER makes sense, I started to think if maybe there's a faster solution, but considering the speed of modern sorting algorithms, probably even starting with knowledge of a real (short) edge, and then comparing all with a threshold (+/- 20% or so) would be significantly slower...

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to get the answer from a friend more experienced with Blender.
Here are the steps

1. Install this plugin - https://github.com/rpopovici/mesh-utils/releases
2. Import model, transform faces to quads, then select the new "Overlapping" faces from the new option in the selection menu and delete those faces
3. After that distance merge vertices
4. Do a limited dissolve on all the mesh
5. Select Interior meshes now (with the Bake Cycle variant) and delete them

With this models got close to 100% correctness.

Comment: I don't want to sound salty, but...  "close to 100%" sounds quite bad, for how simple the task is. If it's not repeatable then I wouldn't bother using any tools at all, otherwise look for [100% accurate answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/238127/60486) - just select everything, F3: limited dissolve, run the script, done! 

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady with the revelation of triangulated voxels  amended my answer from dupe  to this question.  Suggest you do same.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady you are correct, thanks a lot for that, a lot easier then to click around too. You are also right we need to apply this process to a lot models.