# How to Animate a letter giving it the stretchy effects

Tags: animation, effects

Good day, please how do i make a letter bounce in blender? like the cartoon-ish effect. Example: Just the way the letter I bounces in Pixar intro logo

[image] (https://youtu.be/eWGoXdpjU5g).

Something like that. Thank you.

Comment: Technically you could either animate it with hand and deform it with some other object or simulate it with soft body/cloth sim, it really depends on what exactly do you want to acomplish

Comment: maybe you could make use of the shape keys, https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/animation/shape_keys/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Just two of many ideas:

### Simple

Simply make the letter wider when you make it shorter. You can use a *Maintain Volume* constraint so that when you scale the object on one axis, it automatically scales on other axes to keep the same volume:

[image]

### Cloth pressure

Using increment snapping [image], duplicate the default cube to create a letter:

[image]

1. In *Edit Mode* apply this [script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/238127/60486). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> *Invert Selection*, <kbd>X</kbd> *Remove*, <kbd>F</kbd> *Faces*, to get rid of internal geometry.
2. Select 3 bottom-most and 3 top-most faces, [image] *Object Data*, [image] *Add Vertex Group*, [image] *Assign*, name it `PIN`.
3. <kbd>Tab</kbd> *Object Mode*, add two shape keys, leave the 2nd active, <kbd>Tab</kbd> *Edit Mode*, select only a bottom-most face, change [image] *Transform Pivot Point* to [image] *Active Element*, <kbd>A</kbd> select everything, <kbd>S</kbd> *Scale* <kbd>Z</kbd> on Z axis, so the letter is shorter.
4. <kbd>Tab</kbd> *Object Mode*, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> *Subdivision Modifier*.
5. [image] *Physics* [image] *Cloth*, [image] enable *Pressure*, two sections below in section *Shape* → *Pin Group* input `PIN`.

[image]

6. Animate the 2nd shape key value starting after the cloth stabilizes.
7. Now *draw the rest of the owl*, I tried self-collisions, *Pressure* of `2.0`, *Tension* = `1.0` and *Compression* = `2.0` for both *Stiffness* and *Damping*

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a quite old animation. Don't you think they used a lattice? ... in the days of softimage?

Comment: @brockmann I didn't analyze it thoroughly, looks like simple scaling to me, but maybe it's more nuanced. Surely not cloth sim.

Comment: Yep, appreciate the answer either way.

Comment: @brockmann I was at college doing 3D in the 90's.. we had FFD, (Lattice) and we wrote our own  stretch-and-squash, crudely approximating volume preservation, back then. My guess, it's that.

Comment: Interesting @RobinBetts Seems to have paid off, there are still new ideas around it: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00599442/file/HBBEH12-preprint.pdf

Comment: @brockmann Ahh!  Thanks! Theirs much more sophisticated than ours. Ours didn't minimise a deviation.. we simply defined one dimension as squash, and allowed the others to be driven by it. (No computation on the GPU available for us, either)