# How do I create voxel (3D pixel) art in Blender?

Tags: modeling

I appreciate if anyone know how to build this model by which software or online platform? It is much thinkful to good to know about this.

Alternatively, how to build this model easily by some manner or technique?

Thanks a lot.....

[image]

Comment: I've edited my answer in order to answer your question about tilted objects

Comment: it would be helpful if you mentioned how you will use the end product. does it need to be a VOX file or an OBJ file with .MTL? or just a simple render out for NFT image?

Answer (score 9):

There's a modifier called *Remesh* (in *Blocks* mode) that allows you to create this low-poly style from a round object (the *Octree Depth* value defines the block size), it may help you. When you're good, just apply the modifier:

[image]

For tilted object, as you show in your post, just apply the rotation of your object (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

1. Start a new project.
2. Go to *Geometry Nodes* tab on the very top of the Blender window.
3. Press a button in the center of the screen to add a new node tree: [image]
4. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> search for node *Instance on Points*. Drag it onto the existing link to insert as intermediary step. Drag the *Instance* input socket to the left, and drop to get a prompt for a new node - choose *Cube* primitive:

[image]

5. Go back to the *Layout* tab.
6. <kbd>Tab</kbd> Enter *Edit Mode*.
7. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> for *X-Ray* mode:

[image]

8. Everything should be selected like on the image above - if not, <kbd>A</kbd>.
9. <kbd>M</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to merge vertices, so there's just one.
10. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> Enable Snap [image]
11. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to create new vertices and move it around. If you place a vertex by clicking, you can still move it again by <kbd>G</kbd>:

[image]

Consider turning on *Cavity*:

[image]

Now you can preview your model by <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> switching *X-Ray* mode:

[image]

In order to color your mesh, you will have to add *Realize Instances* node, and apply the modifier:

[image]

[image]

A tutorial on low poly models - linked to the timestamp about coloring:

[Learn Low Poly Modeling in Blender 2.9 / 2.8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jHUY3qoBu8)

In future you may want to remove internal faces:

[How to combine multiple cubes with double faces?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/140673/60486)

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a **Voxel Editor** like these (examples):

[KenShape](https://tools.kenney.nl/kenney-shape/)

[Mega Voxels](https://www.megavoxels.com/)

[Qubicle](https://www.minddesk.com/)

[VoxEdit](https://www.voxedit.io/#/en/)

Answer (score 2):

[MagicaVoxel](https://ephtracy.github.io/) is probably the most popular app to create 3D-pixel models like one you presented.

Answer (score 1):

**Remesh modifier** is the easiest method

This might not be convenient however here is an alternative method. Using Minecraft(yes I'm talking about the game) as base editor

1. Create a superflat world
2. Make your pixel art in that world
3. Save and exit Minecraft
4. Open
   [Mineways](https://www.realtimerendering.com/erich/minecraft/public/mineways/) then open your map tweak settings then export as .obj file
5. Then import .obj file in blender
6. In 3d view [MCPREP](https://theduckcow.com/dev/blender/mcprep/) tab
   click prep material
7. This will apply block materials
8. Then change materials as you wish

**This method isn't free because you have to pay for the game**